# yii2-grid EditableColumn invalid ajax url only for the element of the first row and first column

Tags: yii2, yii2-widget

I find a very strange problem using the [yii2-grid](http://demos.krajee.com/grid) by kartik. When I use the EditableColumn plugin and set the form action to a specific url, it seems to be working for all the elements of the grid except for the top left element, the one in the first row and first column.

My grid is very simple, it has 3 columns all of which need to use the editable column plugin. All other elements update correct. The problematic element seems to ignore the `action` paramter passed in the `formOptions` configuration parameter of the Editable Column plugin.

Has anyone else met this problem and managed to find the cause?

Comment: Have you added `indexBy` in the dataProvider's query for the grid?

Comment: Yes, I have, the problem happens only for the element of the first row/column. all others work as should.

Comment: It would be good to see the code of your GridView.

Comment: met this problem today. Nothing special in code. Can confirm that the first column of first row is indeed submited wrong.

Comment: Error occurs when GridView placed in another form. Looking for solution further.